# How to use already opened browser in webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium

I have requirement that everytime i login, it asking security code in webapp. But it will ask only once since browser stored the cookies.but it is asking again and again in selenium webdriver since driver always opening new browser every time.
So i need to use already opened browser in selenium webdriver java. please help me with example code.

Comment: If browser is opened then selenium will run in open browser only.

Comment: You could reuse the same profile each time to bypass login or you can reuse cookies  from a previous session.

Comment: Thanks shreyansh and grasshopper.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found solution that using google chrome option in java. It stores cookies in your temp file and reusing it everytime.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=D:/temp/");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","res/chromedriver.exe");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
driver1 = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```